# Invertible element vs zero divisor in a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a ring and $x,y\in R$ such that $yx=1$ and $xy\ne 1$. Prove there is $z\ne 0$ such that $yz=zx=0$.

My first thought is that y is not an invertible element. Does that mean that it is a zero divisor? (Actually,a left zero divisor,as right zero divisor can't be). If so,there'd be a z' such that yz'=0 and a z'' as z''x=0 and I should prove that z'=z''? What should I do?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$y(xy-1)=yxy-y=y-y=0$$
and
$$(xy-1)x=xyx-x=x-x=0$$
so $xy-1$ is the element you want.